# ListBox binding behaving differently than TextBlock binding

Tags: wpf

Here is the property that fires PropertyChanged:

```
public override List<Tag> Tags
{
    get
    {
        return base.Tags;
    }
    set
    {
        if (base.Tags != value) {
            base.Tags = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, 
                         new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Tags"));
                PropertyChanged(this, 
                         new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TotalTagPages"));
                PropertyChanged(this, 
                         new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PageHasTags"));
             }
        }

    }
}
```

This control refreshes correctly when CurrentPage.Tags is modified:

```
<TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Name="TagHeader" 
    Text="{Binding CurrentPage.Tags,
         Converter={converter:EnumerableToSpacedString}}"    
    Foreground="White" />
```

**This one does NOT refresh when CurrentPage.Tags is changed, but does so when CurrentPage itself is changed:**

```
<ListBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Style="{StaticResource DarkListBox}"  
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplateNoCounts}" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPage.Tags}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>  
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say *"changed"* you mean `Tags` is getting set to another list, right?

Comment: Do you have binding errors enabled in the Output window?  If so (and if not do it) are there any binding errors?

Comment: @HarryMexican: Don't see any reason why that would not work (as opposed to modifying the list, which requires [`INCC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx))...

Comment: Right, got it... I removed a couple lines of code to simplify the question. I actually do a list.clear() instead of resetting the value, which doesn't work for listbox obviously because of what HB said. Silly of me to remove what I thought could not have been causing the bug from the SO question. If you want more points, just write your comment in an answer and I'll accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not see any reason why that would not work (as opposed to modifying the list, which requires [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx))...